# How to retreive Hashed password and check it against regular password in java and MySql

Tags: java, mysql, hash, bcrypt

I know this question has been asked before, however I did not understand the solutions, I am hashing a password and then entering it into my Mysql database, but to enter it into the database i use setString, this means that when i use Bcrypt.checkpw it gives me the invalid salt version error.

I used the following to get it into my database. and then check it.

```
String password2 = BCrypt.hashpw(newPassword, BCrypt.gensalt()); // hashing it

preparedStatement.setString(2, password2); // entering it into the database
BCrypt.checkpw(loginPassword, str2); // loginpassword is the regular one ans str2 //is from the database
```

and then i get the invalid salt error.

```
    /*
 

    * Click nbfs://nbhost/SystemFileSystem/Templates/Licenses/license-default.txt to change this license
     * Click nbfs://nbhost/SystemFileSystem/Templates/Classes/Class.java to edit this template
     */

package com.mycompany.computerscienceia;
import org.mindrot.jbcrypt.BCrypt;
/**
 *
 * @author Thoma
 */
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.mindrot.jbcrypt.BCrypt;


public class hashPassword {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Login and Registration System");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(600, 200);
        frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 2));

        JLabel usernameLabel = new JLabel("Username:");
        JTextField usernameField = new JTextField();
        JLabel passwordLabel = new JLabel("Password:");
        JPasswordField passwordField = new JPasswordField();
        JLabel passwordVerifyLabel = new JLabel("Verify Password (registration only:");
        JPasswordField passwordVerifyField = new JPasswordField();

        JButton loginButton = new JButton("Login");
        JButton registerButton = new JButton("Register");

        frame.add(usernameLabel);
        frame.add(usernameField);
        frame.add(passwordLabel);
        frame.add(passwordField);
        frame.add(passwordVerifyLabel);
        frame.add(passwordVerifyField);
        
        frame.add(loginButton);
        frame.add(registerButton);

        frame.setVisible(true);

        // Database connection parameters
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/users";
        String user = "root";
        String password = "password";

        // Event handling for login button
        loginButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String username = usernameField.getText();
                String password2 = new String(passwordField.getPassword());
                
                boolean UserNameExists = false;
                
                
                
                if (username.isEmpty() == true) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "username field empty!");
                    
                }
                
                else {
                    if (password2.isEmpty() == true) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "password field empty!");
                        
                }
                    else {
                        try {
                            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
                            System.out.println("Server connected!");
                            // hash the password
                            password2 = BCrypt.hashpw(password2, BCrypt.gensalt());
                            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM user_info WHERE username = ?");
                            preparedStatement.setString(1, username);
                            ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
                            // if the username exists then we need to get the password from this resultset
                            // we need to get the result set into an array and get the password element
                            String data[] = new String[3];
                            String password3 = new String(passwordField.getPassword());
                            resultSet.next();

                            String password = resultSet.getString("password");
                            data[2] = password;
                            String theDatabaseHashedPassword = data[2].toString();

                            System.out.println("password from database is " + theDatabaseHashedPassword);
                            
                            Boolean isTheSame = BCrypt.checkpw(password3,theDatabaseHashedPassword);
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, isTheSame);
                            
                            if (isTheSame == true) {
                                
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Login successful");
                                
                            } else {
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Login failed. Please check your credentials.");
                            }

                            preparedStatement.close();
                            connection.close();
                        } catch (Exception ex) {
                            ex.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
                

                
            }
        });

        // Event handling for register button
        registerButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String username = usernameField.getText();
                String password2 = new String(passwordField.getPassword());
                String passwordVerify = new String(passwordVerifyField.getPassword());
                boolean UserNameExists = false;
                
                if (username.isEmpty() == true) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "username field empty!");
                    
                }
                else {
                    if (password2.isEmpty() == true) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "password field empty!");
                        
                    }
                    else {
                        if (passwordVerify.isEmpty() == true){
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "please verify password!");
                        }
                        else {
                            UserNameExists = checkUsernameUnique(user, password, url, username);
                        System.out.println("username boolean = " + UserNameExists);
                        if (UserNameExists == true) {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "username already exists!");
                         
                        }
                        else {
                            // now the password is verified and username unique we can hash the password.
                            password2 = BCrypt.hashpw(password2, BCrypt.gensalt());
                            try {
                                Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
                                PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO user_info (username, password) VALUES (?, ?)");
                                preparedStatement.setString(1, username);
                                preparedStatement.setString(2, password2);

                                int rowsAffected = preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
                                if (rowsAffected > 0) {
                                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Registration successful!");
                                } else {
                                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Registration failed. Please try again.");
                                }

                                preparedStatement.close();
                                connection.close();
                        } catch (Exception ex) {
                            ex.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        }
                        }
                        
                    }
                }

            }
        });
    }


    public static boolean checkUsernameUnique(String uName, String pWord, String theUrl, String theUsername) {
        boolean unique = false;
        try {
            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(theUrl, uName, pWord);
            System.out.println("Server connected!");
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT username FROM user_info;");
            ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
            
            ArrayList<String> allUNmanes = new ArrayList<>();
            
            while (resultSet.next()) {
                for (int x = 1; x <= resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); x++) {
                    String str = resultSet.getString(x);
                    allUNmanes.add(str);
                    System.out.print(str + "\t");
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
            System.out.println(allUNmanes.toString());
            
            if (allUNmanes.contains(theUsername) == true) {
                System.out.println("username already exists");
                unique = true; 
            }
           // String HashedPassword;
          //  if (pWord == HashedPassword){
          //      then output sucess
          //  }
            
        

            preparedStatement.close();
            connection.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("username boolean = " + unique);
        return unique;
    }


}
```

Comment: Help us help you - share a [mcve]

Comment: Don’t. Have the database do the hashing, and just lookup a row which matches that username and password. If not found, no login. Don’t fetch the user row and match the password yourself.

Comment: @user207421 That is bad advice, because database systems generally don't implement suitable password hashing algorithms like Bcrypt and PBKDF2. Normally, you retrieve the hash using the username, and then provide the hash and the password to a validation function (possibly after extracting information like rounds and salt from the hash and using it to configure the validation, if the validation function doesn't do that by itself).